# Issue with UIImagePickerController library source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

When I open the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary, the frame of the editing view is not in alignment with the picture. Here is my code:

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] ;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.allowsEditing=YES;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Here is a screenshot showing the problem:
[image]

As you can see, the top part of the editing view frame is above the actual image. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This issue only occurs with the iPhone 6 and 6+. Works fine with iPhone 5s.